# Potential damage to boot studs

Tags: football, equipment

I recently purchased new football boots, ACE 16.3 Men's Firm Ground, and I want to test them about at a nearby pitch.

The fastest (non-automobile) route to the pitch is a 12-minute walk along a mostly pavement sidewalk.

Could this damage the studs significantly? Should I:

- Wear regular shoes to the pitch, then put on boots
- Wear boots directly to pitch - the damage is insignificant

Comment: Don't really want to put is as an answer, so comment: Put them on when you're there and walk over there with regular shoes. 1) You'll be more comfortable. A 12 minute walk with studs on a pavement is not the nicest thing to do with them 2) The studs will wear down less quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think really it depends if this is a one of trip or if you visit the pitch regularly.

A one of trip will do minimum damage all though I'd advise trying to walk over in regular shoes. If you did walk over in studs, they wouldn't wear down enough for a match official to disallow you from playing for example, but there would be some damage.

If you go there regularly then I would definitely recommend wearing normal shoes. They will wear down too quickly and become sharp.